# How to call a public class properly

Tags: java

```
//precondition x, y non-negative
class Main {

public int gcd(int x, int y){
  if(x < y)
    return gcd(y, x);
  else if(y == 0)
    return x;
  else
    return gcd(y, x % y);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  //below line of code causes an error : cannot find symbol
  gcd Object = new gcd();

  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to call the public class properly. I've attempted it under the comment but it causes a cannot find symbol error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here *gcd* is not a class its a method and to call a method you can directly call them with the correct parameter like in you example all you have to do is call gcd from main

```
gcd(valueX,valueY);
```

To call a method that's not inside a class you need to create an object of that class and then call the function but in your case, you are calling it from the same class so you don't need an object. One more thing to notice is you are calling a non-static method(gcd) from a static method(main) so you need to declare gcd as static like this

```
public static int gcd(int x, int y);
```

if you prefer to have gcd inside a class then you can do this

```
//GCD class
class GCD{
//class method
 public int gcd_method(int x, int y){
    if(x < y)
    return gcd(y, x);
    else if(y == 0)
    return x;
    else
    return gcd(y, x % y);
  }
}
```

than from your main method you have instantiate a object of GCD class to call the method like this

```
GCD gcd = new GCD();
gcd.gcd_method(valueX,valueY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a class called `Main`, but you have not made any *objects* of this class.

So, you now have two options.

Option one is to **not** make any objects of the `Main` class.  In this case, you will need to declare any functions you write (such as `gcd`) as `static` which means you can run the function without having to make an object first.

For this option, you would declare the `gcd` function like this:

```
 public static int gcd(int x, int y) {
```

and your `main` function could look like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      int answer = gcd(10, 12);
      System.out.println(answer);
 }
```

Option two is to go ahead and make an object of the `Main` class.  In this case, you do not need to make your `gcd` function static, but you do need to create the `Main` object.

For this option, your `main` function could look like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Main mainObject = new Main();
      int answer = mainObject.gcd(10, 12);
      System.out.println(answer);
 }
```

Option two would be a better (and necessary) option if your `Main` class had data fields, but since yours does not, I would recommend Option one.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the class instance

```
Main main = new Main();
int result = main.gcd(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so let's start properly here:

A class is created with the following keywords :

1) `public` - the access modifier ( [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/) are the available access modifiers in java )

2) `class` - which indicates that this is a class

3) `name` - the class name

Putting all of this together will result in something like this :

```
public class Car
{

}
```

Now you see that you have some brackets after your class `{ }`. Inside this block, you can create `methods` which are the equivalent for `functions` in C/C++ if you are more familiar with these.

A method can be created approximately the same with the class. Let's see how:

1) `public` - the access modifier ( same )

2) `return type` - here you need to specify the return type for your method

3) `name` - the method name ( and of course, the parameters if necessary )

Again, we can create something like this :

```
public class Car {
 public void print() {
     System.out.println("Hello world");
 }
}
```

Now that we know how to create a class and a method, we can add some attributes to our class. How are we doing this? Same as above:

1) `public` - the access modifier

2) `type` - the attribute type

3) `name`

This time, I will set the access modifier to private:

```
public class Car {
 private String description;

 public void print() {
     System.out.println("Hello world");
 }
}
```

Now to access the method from the created class, we need to instantiate first the class. The **easiest** way to do this and `test` it is to create a `public static void main(String[] args)` method and do all the stuff inside it:

```
public class Car {
 private String description;

 public void print() {
     System.out.println("Hello world");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Car car = new Car();
 }
}
```

Why do we need to instantiate this? because our method can be called only by an object of `Car` type.

```
public class Car {
 private String description;

 public void print() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Car car = new Car();
     car.print();
     print(); // non-static method can not be referenced from static context -> error
 }
}
```

So now we see that we can do one more thing with our methods and attributes too : make them `static`. After we do this, we can call them without a class instance.

```
public class Car {
 private String description;

 public void print() {
     System.out.println("Hello world");
 }

 public static void printStatic() {
     System.out.println("Hello Static");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Car car = new Car();
     car.print();
     printStatic();
 }
}
```

Now maybe you're wondering what can we do with the `description` attribute ? We can modify it, but again, we need an instance in order to do this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car = new Car();
    car.print();
    printStatic();
    car.description = "Hello car";
    description="e3"; //non-static field again
}
```

And what does `private` means? It means that you can not access the attribute like I did before if you create the `Car` instance in another class like this:

```
public class Dog {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Car car = new Car();
     car.description = "hi"; // "description" has private access in Car - error - can not be compiled.
 }
}
```